# MPAndroid Chart how to remove the line in the background?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mpandroidchart, android-library

I am using MPAndroidChart in my order. But currently, how to remove the line in the background?
there is another question how can I make the word month on the other side?
.....................................................................................................................................................................
Thanks !

---

[image: This image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnChartValueSelectedListener {
    LineChart lineChartDownFill;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initLineChartDownFill();

    }

    private void initLineChartDownFill() {
        lineChartDownFill = findViewById(R.id.chart1);
        lineChartDownFill.setTouchEnabled(true);
        lineChartDownFill.setDragEnabled(true);
        lineChartDownFill.setScaleEnabled(true);
        lineChartDownFill.setPinchZoom(false);
        lineChartDownFill.animateXY(2000, 2000);
        lineChartDownFill.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
        lineChartDownFill.setDrawGridBackground(false);
        lineChartDownFill.setMaxHighlightDistance(200);
        lineChartDownFill.setViewPortOffsets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        lineChartDownFill.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
        lineChartDownFill.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(12);

        MyMarkerView mv = new MyMarkerView(this, R.layout.custom_marker_view);
        mv.setChartView(lineChartDownFill);

        lineChartDownFill.setMarker(mv);
        lineChartDownFillWithData();
    }

    private void lineChartDownFillWithData() {
        Description description = new Description();
        description.setTextColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark1);
        description.setText("month");
        description.setTextSize(10);

        lineChartDownFill.setDescription(description);

        ArrayList<Entry> entryArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        entryArrayList.add(new Entry(1, 12f, "1"));
        entryArrayList.add(new Entry(2, 74f, "2"));
        entryArrayList.add(new Entry(3, 77f, "3"));
        entryArrayList.add(new Entry(4, 31f, "4"));
        entryArrayList.add(new Entry(5, 31f, "5"));
        entryArrayList.add(new Entry(6, 82f, "6"));
        entryArrayList.add(new Entry(7, 40f, "7"));
        entryArrayList.add(new Entry(8, 40f, "8"));
        entryArrayList.add(new Entry(9, 81f, "9"));
        entryArrayList.add(new Entry(10, 90f, "10"));
        entryArrayList.add(new Entry(11, 80f, "11"));
        entryArrayList.add(new Entry(12, 25f, "12"));

        LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(entryArrayList, "This is y bill");

        lineDataSet.setLineWidth(0.1f);
        lineDataSet.setColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark1);
        lineDataSet.setCircleColor(Color.WHITE);
        lineDataSet.setCircleHoleColor(Color.BLACK);
        lineDataSet.setDrawValues(false);
        lineDataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
        lineDataSet.setCircleRadius(5f);
        //lineDataSet.setCubicIntensity(0.2f);
        lineDataSet.setDrawFilled(true);

        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.bg1);
        lineDataSet.setFillDrawable(drawable);

        Legend legend = lineChartDownFill.getLegend();
        legend.setEnabled(false);

        lineDataSet.setDrawCircles(true);

        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> iLineDataSetArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        iLineDataSetArrayList.add(lineDataSet);

        //LineData is the data accord
        LineData lineData = new LineData(iLineDataSetArrayList);
        lineData.setValueTextSize(13f);
        lineData.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        lineChartDownFill.setData(lineData);
        lineChartDownFill.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
        Log.e("Entry selected", e.toString());
        Log.e("LOW HIGH", "low: " + lineChartDownFill.getLowestVisibleX() + ", high: " + lineChartDownFill.getHighestVisibleX());
        Log.e("MIN MAX", "xMin: " + lineChartDownFill.getXChartMin() + ", xMax: " + lineChartDownFill.getXChartMax() + ", yMin: " + lineChartDownFill.getYChartMin() + ", yMax: " + lineChartDownFill.getYChartMax());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected() {
        Log.e("Nothing selected", "Nothing selected.");
    }
}
```